# JavaScript object, seeing expected result using two different ways of calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I don't understand why this is happening.

I need to get the objects `startPoint` which is set on `mousedown` and the current `e.pageY` from the `mousemove` to do some calculations.

```
var adjustHeight = {
    change: function(e) {
        console.log(this.startPoint)
        console.log(e.pageY);
    },
};

$('#dragger').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    adjustHeight.startPoint = e.pageY;
    
    $(window).on('mousemove', adjustHeight.change());
    
    $(window).on('mouseup', function() {
        $(window).off('mousemove', adjustHeight.change())
    });
})
```

However the console prints out the objects `startPoint` which is what I expect but `e.pageY` is undefined,
but when I use this line instead:

```
...
    $(window).on('mousemove', adjustHeight.change);
    
    $(window).on('mouseup', function() {
        $(window).off('mousemove', adjustHeight.change)
    });
...
```

I get the `e.pageY` as expected but now the `startPoint` is undefined. When I checked what `this` was pointing at it was the DOMWindow.

My question is why is this happening and how would I go about getting both objects properties and the functions `e` at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).on('mousemove', adjustHeight.change());
```

is executing `adjustHeight.change` immediately and passing the *return value* to `.on()`. Since you are not passing any argument to `adjustHeight.change`, `e` will be `undefined` (and `e.pageY` won't be available).

---

```
$(window).on('mousemove', adjustHeight.change);
```

correctly passes the function to `.on`, hence later the event object is passed to the handler and you can access `e.pageY`. But the context (`this`) is not `adjustHeight` anymore, it's the DOM element you bound the handler to. Which is `window` in this case and `window` does not have a `startPoint` property.

The MDN documentation has [an excellent article about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (in general), [as does quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) (with respect to event handlers).

---

**Solution**:

Pass a new function as handler, which calls `adjustHeight.change` and passes the `event` object:

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function(event) {
    adjustHeight.change(event);
});
```

or *bind* `adjustHeight.change` to `adjustHeight` using [`$.proxy` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
$(window).on('mousemove', $.proxy(adjustHeight.change, adjustHeight));
```

Since you also want to unbind the handler later, you should either assign it to a variable or use a [namespaced event *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events).

Example:

```
$(window).on('mousemove.dragger', $.proxy(adjustHeight.change, adjustHeight));

$(window).on('mouseup.dragger', function() {
    // removes both, the mousemove and mousup event handlers
    $(window).off('.dragger');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is wrong:

```
$(window).on('mousemove', adjustHeight.change());
```

Then, `change()` is not bound to `adjustHeight` by default. You'd have to do something like:

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function() {
    adjustHeight.change();
});
```

Or, in modern browsers:

```
$(window).on('mousemove', adjustHeight.change.bind(adjustHeight));
```

Answer (score 0):

...

```
$(window).on('mousemove', adjustHeight.change);

$(window).on('mouseup', function() {
    $(window).off('mousemove', adjustHeight.change)
});
```

...

(line:3)

```
console.log("start:" + adjustHeight.startPoint)
```